# Ansible failed_when statement

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, conditional-statements

In the following task I want to make ansible **not** to fail when `stderr` contains `the object has been modified` or `have a resource type`.

```
- name: List nodes
  delegate_to: localhost
  shell: kubectl get nodes
  run_once: true
  register: output_error
  failed_when: (output_error.stderr_lines | length > 0) and ("'the object has been modified' not in output_error.stderr or 'have a resource type' not in output_error.stderr")
```

However I am reveiving the following error message:

```
kubectl get nodes", "delta": "0:00:00.498169", "end": "2022-08-05 11:08:01.386024", "failed_when_result": true, "item": "nodes", "rc": 0, "start": "2022-08-05 11:08:00.887855", "stderr": "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"nodes\"", "stderr_lines": ["error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"nodes\""], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Your `stderr` is `error: the server doesn't have a resource type "nodes"`, so it fails as you asked. Your issue is not with your condition, but with your the `stderr` you are getting.

Comment: I do want to fail when the output is in the `stderr`. Do I need to use `contain`,  could you please show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex which includes both alternatives:

```yaml
- name: List nodes
  delegate_to: localhost
  shell: kubectl get nodes
  run_once: true
  register: output_error
  failed_when:
    - output_error.stderr_lines | length > 0
    - output_error.stderr is not regex('the object has been modified|have a resource type')
```

For easier reading and maintenance you can set your positive matches in a list and join them together in an expression.

```yaml
- name: List nodes
  vars:
    acceptable_err_matches:
      - the object has been modified
      - have a resource type
    match_regex: acceptable_err_matches | map('regex_escape') | join('|')
  delegate_to: localhost
  shell: kubectl get nodes
  run_once: true
  register: output_error
  failed_when:
    - output_error.stderr_lines | length > 0
    - output_error.stderr is not regex(match_regex)
```